# How to group the arguments while using Getopt in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line, command-line-arguments, getopt

To a perl script that I am writing, there can be a lot (~50) of command line options provided. Most of them are optional, so a call will have only some of the options provided.

I am using `Getopt::Long` but it does not allow me to use `GetOptions` more than once. As a result, I have to use all the command line options in one `GetOptions` call.

**Is there some good way to group the options while using `GetOptions`?**

```
$ cat test.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($a, $b, $c, $d);

GetOptions ('a=s' => \$a, 'b=s' => \$b);
GetOptions ('c=s' => \$c, 'd=s' => \$d);

print "a = $a\nb = $b\nc = $c\nd = $d\n";

$ perl test.pl -a=AA -b=BB -c=CC -d=DD
Unknown option: c
Unknown option: d
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 10.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 10.
a = AA
b = BB
c = 
d = 
$
```

Answer (score 6):

It may be a good idea to store your options in a hash instead:

See [`Getopt::Long` : Storing options values in a hash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong) :

---

> Sometimes, for example when there are
>   a lot of options, having a separate
>   variable for each of them can be
>   cumbersome. `GetOptions()` supports, as
>   an alternative mechanism, storing
>   options values in a hash.
>
> To obtain this, a reference to a hash
>   must be passed as the first argument
>   to `GetOptions()`. For each option that
>   is specified on the command line, the
>   option value will be stored in the
>   hash with the option name as key.
>   Options that are not actually used on
>   the command line will not be put in
>   the hash, on other words,
>   `exists($h{option})` (or `defined()`) can
>   be used to test if an option was used.
>   The drawback is that warnings will be
>   issued if the program runs under use
>   strict and uses `$h{option}` without
>   testing with `exists()` or `defined()`
>   first.
>
> ```
> my %h = ();
> GetOptions (\%h, 'length=i');       # will store in $h{length}
> ```
>
> For options that take list or hash values, it is
>   necessary to indicate this by
>   appending an @ or % sign after the
>   type:
>
> ```
> GetOptions (\%h, 'colours=s@');     # will push to @{$h{colours}}
> ```
>
> To make things more complicated, the hash may
>   contain references to the actual
>   destinations, for example:
>
> ```
> my $len = 0;
> my %h = ('length' => \$len);
> GetOptions (\%h, 'length=i');       # will store in $len
> ```
>
> This example is fully equivalent with:
>
> ```
> my $len = 0;
> GetOptions ('length=i' => \$len);   # will store in $len
> ```
>
> Any mixture is possible. For example, the most
>   frequently used options could be
>   stored in variables while all other
>   options get stored in the hash:
>
> ```
> my $verbose = 0;                    # frequently referred
> my $debug = 0;                      # frequently referred
> my %h = ('verbose' => \$verbose, 'debug' => \$debug);
> GetOptions (\%h, 'verbose', 'debug', 'filter', 'size=i');
> if ( $verbose ) { ... }
> if ( exists $h{filter} ) { ... option 'filter' was specified ... }
> ```

Comment: +1 - Among other reasons, once you start doing any complicated development, having options in individual variables instead of a hash you can pass as a whole to object constructors is Very Painful.

Answer (score 2):

The most direct answer is to use Getopt::Long::Configure like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($a, $b, $c, $d);

Getopt::Long::Configure( qw(pass_through) );
GetOptions ('a=s' => \$a, 'b=s' => \$b);

Getopt::Long::Configure( qw(no_pass_through) );
GetOptions ('c=s' => \$c, 'd=s' => \$d);

print "a = $a\nb = $b\nc = $c\nd = $d\n";
```

Note that you should make sure that your last invocation of GetOptions should be configured with **no_pass_through** to make sure that you get warnings about unknown options.

```
% perl test_getop.pl -a AA -b BB -c CC -d DD -e EE
Unknown option: e
a = AA
b = BB
c = CC
d = DD
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with:

```
GetOptions(
  'a=s' => \$a,
  'b=s' => \$b,
  'c=s' => \$c,
  'd=s' => \$d,
);
```

Or, if they're all short, you could do:

```
GetOptions(
  'a=s' => \$a,   'b=s' => \$b,
  'c=s' => \$c,   'd=s' => \$d,
);
```

(Note that it's a bad idea to use `$a` and `$b` for anything except `sort` comparisions.)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I have about 50 of them, and if they are not grouped, it is difficult to keep track of them.

Comment: @Lazer, then you're going to have to better explain what you mean by "grouped".  GetOptions doesn't care what order they're listed in; list them in whatever order makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally arrays are flattened out into a single list before being passed to a function, although some functions override this behavior.  Using this you can define arrays of option groups and pass the list of arrays to GetOptions.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my ( $opt_a, $opt_b, $opt_c, $opt_d );

my @opt_group_1 = ( 'a=s' => \$opt_a, 'b=s' => \$opt_b );
my @opt_group_2 = ( 'c=s' => \$opt_c, 'd=s' => \$opt_d );
GetOptions( @opt_group_1, @opt_group_2 );

print "a = $opt_a\nb = $opt_b\nc = $opt_c\nd = $opt_d\n";
```

You can combine this with storing values in a hash to prevent having to create a huge number of option variables as Zaid mentioned.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my @opt_group_1 = ( 'a=s', 'b=s' );
my @opt_group_2 = ( 'c=s', 'd=s' );

my %opt;

GetOptions( \%opt, @opt_group_1, @opt_group_2 );

print "a = $opt{a}\nb = $opt{b}\nc = $opt{c}\nd = $opt{d}\n";
```